# Kanji identification

Tags: kanji

What's the 2nd kanji in the image below?
I know that the first one is for oni, the second is 'mushi'.
Can't seem to figure out what comes before 'mushi' though !

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 触

Composed of 角 + 虫.

Read [触]{さわ}る in this case.